# examples for move constructor/assignment operator that effect correctness?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was wandering if there are any examples where not implementing move semantics (i.e., move constructor and move assignment operator) will effect the correctness of the program and not only its performance.

Comment: Would your question be assuming that this hypothetical type has properly implemented copy semantics?

Comment: @NicolBolas  any assumption that helps finding an example

Comment: I am not sure why the downvote? I think it is a legitimate question, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three states that "Unlike Rule of Three, failing to provide move constructor and move assignment is usually not an error, but a missed optimization opportunity." and I was wandering about the "usually" part

Comment: "usually not" -> "never" the copy con not being there might be an error.

Comment: This is a bit open ended, but a case where an object manages an underlying resource is a good example. Even assuming the complier elides a copy-assign to a copy, there will be a point where the resource is alive in two objects. Explicitly disabling copy ctor / assign makes a lot of sense in such contexts. To build on @NicolBolas's answer, I have (simple) OpenGL shader and program classes that explicitly define 'move' copy / assign, because I never want a copy. I can pass these things around by (r)value - simplifying my design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be any value type where implementing copy semantics is one (or more) of the following:

- Irrational (aka: antithetical to the design of the class)
- Impossible
- Incurs a cost that can lead to program termination/deadlocking

The "irrational" category would be for types like `unique_ptr`, where the logical design of the type makes copying nonsensical.

The "impossible" category would include wrapper types for many APIs that exist outside of your system.

Consider a wrapper type for some OpenGL object. You might think that, because OpenGL is a query-able API (you can query every piece of state set into it) that you could reasonably implement object copying by getting the state from the old object and setting it in the new one.

But this is flawed because of OpenGL extensions. They can give objects new state, which your code written before those extensions would know nothing about.

The final category sounds odd. But let's take that OpenGL wrapper idea. Let's say you implement copying. And you're copying a buffer object (a section of GPU memory).

Well... where are you doing that copying? Are you doing it on a thread that has an OpenGL context current? Is that object being updated simultaneously in another thread, such that you've somewhere else, such that you've created a race condition?

You could try to use mutexes to avoid the race condition, but now you've created the very real possibility of deadlocking. Why? Because many objects contain buffer objects. And copying those objects would naturally need to copy their containing buffers. So you have a multi-copy operation that has to lock multiple mutexes to do its job. That can deadlock against some other multi-copy operation, if they're copying the same buffers.

So either you take a chance on deadlocking, you take a chance on getting inconsistent memory copies... or you don't allow copying at all.

And if your type doesn't allow copying, then unless the type's design says otherwise, you ought to allow moving.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm going to assume you're implying there's no way to copy this class too.)

Well, an example is `std::unique_ptr`. Because this pointer is supposed to have sole ownership of an object dynamically allocated with `new` it wouldn't make any sense to allow a copy constructor because we can't have 2 owners. However, a move assignment operator and a move constructor are implemented to still allow moving over the object that was allocated. Because we're moving, the moved-from `unique_ptr` will no longer have ownership over the object but now the moved-to `unique_ptr` owns this object. This doesn't violate the sole ownership part. If we didn't have these move semantics then `unique_ptr` would have far less use cases.

To be more general, as long as you don't try to move an object without a move assignment operator/ move constructor then there technically never is a situation which will "*will effect the correctness of the program*". Very specific classes have this NotCopyable/NotMovable restraint e.g `std::mutex` because it wouldn't make sense for these classes to do so. Note that pre-C++17 just returning an object from a function requires it to be either Copyable or Movable already so use cases for these classes are limited.